# Method call that fetches data. Can it be made reactive?

Tags: meteor

I want to get data from a number of queries on the same collection, and unfortunately this is not yet supported on meteor. That's why I tried to do something like this:

**Common**

```
Dep = new Deps.Dependency;
```

**Server**

```
Meteor.methods({
    fetch: function(){
       var results = Data.find(dataQuery).fetch();
       var otherResults = Data.find(queryThatCannotBeCombinedWithPrevious).fetch(); 

       return results.concat(otherResults);
    },
    save: function(data){
         Data.insert(data);
         Dep.changed();
    }
    update: function(data){
         Data.update({_id: data._id}, data);
         Dep.changed();
    }
});
```

**Client**

```
Session.setDefault('combinedData', []);
Template.demo.data = function(){    
    Dep.depend();
    Meteor.call('fetch',function(error, data){
        Session.set('combinedData', data);
    });
    return Session.get('combinedData');
};
```

This doesn't work though, propably because the Dep variable on the client is different from the Dep on the server. Is there a way to make the method call reactive when the contents of the `Data` collection change?

**Notes**

I am currently using Meteor 0.8.1.1, which doesn't allow subscriptions that return multiple cursors of the same collection yet.

Comment: `changed` only runs on the client. Before I spend more time on this, is there a reason why you can't just separate `dataQuery` and `queryThatCannotBeCombinedWithPrevious` into two publications and subscribe to both of them? That seems like a much easier solution.

Comment: If you mean multiple subscriptions before a single query I assumed that brings the union of those subscriptions, while I want all the results. Am I wrong on that?

Comment: Multiple subscriptions for the same collection will send the union of the documents to the client (which you can then query for exactly the result you want). If the original problem was "I can't return 2 cursors for the same collection in a publish function", the solution is "make 2 publish functions and subscribe to both" - you will get the same result (assuming meteor allowed the former). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The original reason I couldn't merge those queries in an `$or` block was that mongodb wouldn't allow those specific queries to run like that (an $in query and a $near query). If that doesn't happen with multiple subscriptions, it's cool. I'll check it after work and let you know

Comment: Just have to point out that I do not want the union of the results, I want the total in a single server request if possible :/

Comment: Ah now I get it! The critical piece of information was that the semantics of the query require that it run only on the server, or you have to run 2 queries on the client and then de-duplicate them yourself. The de-duplication may be as easy as fetching both sets, concatenating them, and then running `_.uniq`. But Hubert's answer may end up being less code to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a small hack and you're close. First, you need a client–only dependence, the server just passes a data returned from the method and doesn't share variables (also there's nothing on the server that requires deps). Second, you only want to fetch the actual variable once, otherwise you'll end up with an infinite loop.

Example implementation:

```
var value = null;
var valueInitialized = false;
var valueDep = new Deps.Dependency();

Template.demo.data = function() {
  valueDep.depend();
  if(!valueInitialized) {
    valueInitialized = true;

    Meteor.call('fetchData', function(err, result) {
      value = result;
      valueDep.changed();
    });
  }
  return value;
};
```

Comment: Note that it's all client–side code, the method on the server can look however you like.

Comment: I tried this, but when the `Data` collection contents change (say, from another tab) the template stays the same but if I set the `valueInitialized` to false and re-run `valueDep.changed()` it updates. I assume this is the best I can get under the circumstances, so I'll leave it like this and wait for version 1.0

Comment: If you want to fetch again, yes, the correct method is to falsify `valueInitialized` and change the dep. You can do this in `Template.rendered`, or in an observer, or wherever you need this.